# How to perform form submit?

Tags: c++, mshtml

In javascript we can do a form submit using

```
document.getElementById('edit').form.submit();
```

I want to know how we can do this using `IHTMLElement` in C++?

I tried getting the form element from the page and used `IHTMLElement->click()` api.

But no action is performed.

How can I get a "FORM" element from the page and do the submit?

Comment: Can you try to select the submit button element, instead of the form?

Comment: You must be sure that you have filled out all mandantory elements in the form!

Answer (score 1):

Once you have retrieved an IHTMLElement from the document use `QueryInterface` to get a pointer to the `IHTMLFormElement` interface. One you've done that call `submit()`.

```
IHTMLFormElement *form;
hr = element->QueryInterface(
    IID_IHTMLFormElement,
    reinterpret_cast<void**>(&form));
if(!FAILED(hr))
{
    form->submit();
    form->Release();
}
```

Keep in mind that this will not fire the forms `onsubmit` event. You will need to do that yourself by calling `HTMLFormElementEvents::onsubmit` which can be done in much the same way as the `submit` example above.